Show page number formatting in TOC
I've searched...not sure there is a way to do this.
-I have a doc set up with a multi-level list and headings - works and looks great.
-I have formatted my page numbers to include the chapter number for my Appendices (A-1, A-2, B1, etc.) and they also look as I want them to (yay!).
However my TOC will only show the numeric, sequential page numbering (1-40, for example), when I would like it to show 1-30 (main part of the doc), and then A-1, A-2, etc., for my appendices - meaning exactly how they're formatted.
I can't find anything in custom TOC or modify TOC field that will allow this.  I don't want to have to manually put the page number in because this doc will become a template...being able to update fields is necessary.
Help me pleeeaase!  And Thank you.

I've figured this out and thought I would post it in case anyone else has the same issue...I needed to put SEQ field  in each appendix, and then add that into my TOC field code: {SEQ appx * ALPHABETIC * MERGEFORMAT} at the start of each chapter, then TOC field looks like this: {TOC \h \z \s appx \d "-" \t APPENDIX,1,Appendix2,2,Appendix3,3"} resulting in TOC page numbers like A-1, A-2, A-3, B-1, etc.  Yippee!!
